# Paper ejecting from printer when sending manual command codes

Tags: .net, printing, epson

I am programming for the printer Epson TM-H5000II.

I trying to print the slip paper when call the function ESC c 0 4.

The basic steps I'm using:

1. Manual Insert the Paper
2. call ESC c 0 4 (Select Slip Paper)

The problem is that after calling ESC c 0 4 the paper will eject from printer.

How can I tell the printer stop eject my paper from printer?

Can this be done or is limitation of the printer?

---

update 2013-03-16

I found another Epson document. I am trying to try disable the TOF and BOF sensor .
But I am not sure my code is correct or wrong.
Hope someone can give me some hint to solve the problem.
Thank You

Here is the document.
Page 1
  http://postimage.org/image/i0mffniv9
Page 2
  [http://postimage.org/image/ev1tpg091](http://postimage.org/image/ev1tpg091/)

Below is my code

```
Dim SerialPort1 As New SerialPort("COM1")
SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
SerialPort1.StopBits = 1
SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
SerialPort1.WriteBufferSize = 4096
If SerialPort1.IsOpen = False Then SerialPort1.Open()
If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
    'SerialPort1.DiscardInBuffer()
    'SerialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer()
        'Initialize Printer 
    Dim BufferInitialize() As Byte = {&H1B, &H40}
    SerialPort1.Write(BufferInitialize, 0, BufferInitialize.Length)
    ''Enable(SLip) ESC c 1 4
            Dim Buffer5() As Byte = {&H1B, &H63, &H31, &H4}
    SerialPort1.Write(Buffer5, 0, Buffer5.Length)
    'Disable sensor
    Dim BufferTOF() As Byte = {&H1B, &H63, &H34, &H10}
    SerialPort1.Write(BufferTOF, 0, BufferTOF.Length)
    'Disable sensor
    Dim BufferBOF() As Byte = {&H1B, &H63, &H34, &H20}
    SerialPort1.Write(BufferBOF, 0, BufferBOF.Length)
    'Enable(SLip) ESC c 0 4
    Dim Buffer2() As Byte = {&H1B, &H63, &H30, &H4}
    SerialPort1.Write(Buffer2, 0, Buffer2.Length) 

    SerialPort1.WriteLine("WHY")
    'Release
    Dim BufferEnd() As Byte = {&H1B, &H71}
    SerialPort1.Write(BufferEnd, 0, BufferEnd.Length) 
End If
If SerialPort1.IsOpen = True Then SerialPort1.Close()
```